# как получить последний сегмент url ? Laravel, php

Tags: php, laravel

http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/category/transmission-oil или к примеру такой http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/products/category/transmission-oil нужно всегда получать последний transmission-oi вместо него может быть другой

получал так но в одном случае он 3 в другом 4

```
@if($category->slug === Request::segment(3)
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

нашел
last(request()->segments())